# Recommended set of image sizes and densities to supply for android icon & button?

Tags: android, image, button, icons, scale

I want to create some icon and button images to be used in android. The images can be uniformly scaled/stretched over the allocated layout space(no intricate definition of minimum size in regions etc). I would like to cover all the screen sizes and density range.

(from [link to Dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)) The range for the sizes of screens is small, normal large and extra large. For the denstieis it is ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi. So there are 4 sizes and 4 densities. Do I need to supply 4x4 different images? If I needed to, I could imagine configuring Adobe Illustrator to export this way, but is it necessary?

What are the practical spacing between these options which reasonably cover the needs for sizes and densities in this case? A rule of thumb answer from experience would be appreciated if a more technical justification does not apply.

(note: the corners are simple right angles)
(in the Dev guide, [link for qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers), qualifiers are mentioned for Size as well as Density but in the examples for the resource folders no differentiation is made for the sizes which may be different which I find confusing. Or am I missing some fundamental understanding on how the sizes are being taken care of?)
EDIT: From this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size), connected to @Budgie comment below for the icons there is a recommended size and density for icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be useful for you: [icon_templates pack](http://developer.android.com/shareables/icon_templates-v4.0.zip)

This is a pack of icon templates for different screen sizes and densities.

Comment: the set looks interesting. It is linked from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html which gives some good guildlines. But they only prescribe having sets for the individual densities and ignore the sizes

Comment: Also this link is important as a side note http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870 for supplying other images.

Comment: when I open the template files in photoshop the resolution in the image size is always 72 although the size dimensions vary correctly.